# Select single value from db

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to select a single value from my db.

**MyController.cs**

```
    using (var db = new MainDbContext())
    {
        var getPhoto = db.Users.Where(u => u.Name == User.Identity.Name).Select(u => u.Photo);
        var materializePhoto = getPhoto.ToList();
        var photo = materializePhoto[0];
    }
```

I do this stuff in order to properly convert my value from *IQueryable* to *String*.

I've read about using 'FirstOrDefault', 'First', 'Default' select options (cause they return a string value, not IQuerable) but I think it isn't suitable for my case.

**The question is: how can I make my code simplier and shorter?**

P.S.: **db.Users.Photo** contains url's.

Comment: `var photo = db.Users.Where(u => u.Name == User.Identity.Name).Select(u => u.Photo).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Or you could write even shorter: `var photo = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == User.Identity.Name).Select(u => u.Photo);`

Comment: @marc_s, I heard about eager loading, smth like I select not the whole table but necessary row at once.. Like it decreases using memory and traffic. Is that true? And can I do this in my code? Where can I read about it in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `FirstOrDefault` to your code

```
var getPhoto = db.Users.Where(u => u.Name == User.Identity.Name).Select(u => u.Photo).FirstOrDefault();
```

and yes, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You could do like this also

```
var photo = db.Users.Where(u => u.Name == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault().Photo;
```

It will also return the first photo value

Answer (score 1):

Please use FirstOrDefault() to select single record from db.